# RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801JIR (ICH10R) SATA RAID Controller

Tags: linux, supermicro, fakeraid, dmraid

```
RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801JIR (ICH10R) SATA RAID Controller
    Subsystem: Super Micro Computer Inc Unknown device 0007
```

Is any one know which Linux utility I can install on my server to manage above said RAID device from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of management do you expect? ICH10R-based RAID controllers are so called fake- or software-RAID controllers, the OS needs to do all the work. There are numerous writeups, walkthroughs and howtos on how to get software RAID working with [dmraid](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmraid), here is one [specifically written for Ubuntu users](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto).

Comment: My server have h/w raid. I meant tools like mpt-status. For this RAID mpt-status is not working. My actually need is to know status of my raid device from command line.

Comment: Hard to believe that - ICH10R is *not* a hardware RAID controller. Could you provide the output of `dmraid -r` and `dmraid -s` please by posting it to your original question?

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. It was a fake raid. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto. I was able to manage it using `dmraid`

Comment: Glad it worked. Feel free to either write a more detailed answer to your own question and mark it as the "correct answer" for the posterity or just mark this one as "correct" to give a hint to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try MegaCli - I use it for manage and monitoring purposes. LSI provides Linux-version of this utility and related lib in rpm packages.